# Why is Mule required if we have Active MQ?

Tags: java, jms

I am working as a software engineer on a project which uses ActiveMQ and Mule for Java Messaging Service. But I have one question: since ActiveMQ is transferring all message to one queue to another queue, why Mule is required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: From the Mule Documentation]

The above image is from the official [Mule 3 User Manual](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Application+Architecture)

*Following is a very simplistic overview to give you a general idea.  Without knowing the specifics about your application, its difficult to tell how everything works together.*

Mule is not a message broker, it is a service bus; it provides integration and communication services.  In a basic form, it *can act like a message broker*, but that's just a side effect of any integration layer.

The real power of mule is the various integration points across different applications, system, and services; providing for security, reporting, etc.

ActiveMQ is just a message broker - whole job is to effectively provide a messaging bus. Mule takes different requests, transform/translates them, logs them, and may then posts them on to ActiveMQ as part of its defined flow.

It could also be that ActiveMQ is acting as the queue for messages that later need to be processed through Mule (as in the image above).

Mule can use ActiveMQ as a message source and destination. Using MQ in such a way provides a guarantee that messages will be processed and none are lost.